# Every time I create a table timestamp automatically adds ON UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, timestamp, create-table

When I make a table with a timestamp attribute, it automatically adds an ON UPDATE attribute. I don't want the column to update when I edit that row. How do I manually set in the the .sql when I create the table that ON UPDATE do nothing.

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    ...

    date_added    timestamp
                  NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```

Comment: If you defined the column as NOT NULL and NOT supplied value on INSERT, it will be set to NOW. Alter the column definition to NULL or supply value. Details: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html#idm140351504650288

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's why you'd use a `TIMESTAMP` column in the first place, they have the special property of being automatically assigned like that.

If you don't want this behaviour, use a `DATETIME` instead. These have additional advantages, like actually working 18 years from now when [2038 rolls around and ruins everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) based on 32-bit time values.

Comment: Wait is `timestamp` and `TIMESTAMP` 2 different things?

Comment: MySQL's keywords are case-insensitive, so no, they're the same thing. SQL keywords, including column types, are traditionally written ALL-CAPS.

Comment: Does datetime have a timezone? I really get confused with the timezones because my server is in PST time and I am in AEST time.

Comment: The cardinal rule is to always store your data on the server in UTC and map to local time depending on user preferences in the application layer. This is because in MySQL these fields don't have time-zone information baked in, and baking in time-zone information is really, really hard because time-zones change in all sorts of unpredictable and often nonsensical ways.